# How to fix non-required custom option using radio buttons from not allowing products to be added in magento 2 manual order entry?

Tags: magento2

When building an order in magento 2 v2.32 and adding a product to the order, we have found that if you use radio buttons, for custom option set that are NOT required, it will NOT allow you to add the product to an order. The NONE option that is automatically created is somehow not seen as an actual option, so the product can't be configured, and thus will not add product to manual order.

Any ideas?